# Are there $k$ for which $\sigma_k$ is an injection?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Does there exist $k \in N$ such that $ \sigma_k(n) $ is an injective function, where $\sigma_k(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$ raised to the $k$th power. If so what is the minimum value of $k$ with this property?

The cases $k=1$ and $k=2$ are easily seen to be false, but for $k>2$, is there a known solution?

Comment: I would guess the answer is no, since for any $k$, there are positive integers expressible as a sum of a prescribed number of $k$-th powers in more than one way. In fact I would think there are infinitely many of these positive integers for each $k$ and $N$, the number of parts allowed in the sum. But I am no expert.

Comment: True, but it really seems plausible, just from looking on wolfram alpha, that for a large enough k , the function would be strictly increasing meaning it would be injective.

Comment: For $k,n > 1$ we have $$n^k < \sigma_k(n) < n^k\cdot \zeta(k)\,.$$ Thus if $\sigma_k(n) = \sigma_k(m)$ for $n < m$ we must have $n < m < \sqrt[k]{\zeta(k)}\cdot n$. The factor is small if $k$ isn't too small, so repeated values can only be expected for _large_ $n$.

Comment: And, whatever value $k$ has, if $p$ is a sufficiently large prime, then $\sigma_k(p) < \sigma_k(p-1)$.